# NSTableView Randomly Empty on Load

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` that uses a view controller as an `NSTableViewDataSource`. Sometimes the table and its data load just fine, but other times it’s just blank, and the data source methods aren’t called. Why this random behaviour, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: When do you call reloadData on your tableview? Maybe to early and the datasource is not yet filled?

Comment: Woah, woah, what’s with the downvotes? I merely asked/answered my own question in hopes that somebody facing a similar bug (it’s definitely a bug, shouldn’t work like this) could fix it for their app with relatively minor frustration.

Comment: @Volker : Thank you, you were sorta right. I actually wasn’t calling `-reloadData` at all, because up until this point all my other table views loaded automatically with no manual intervention required. This case, however, was different. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I missed an *extremely important* paragraph on `NSTableView`’s documentation documentation:

> **Important**
>
> It’s possible that your data source methods for populating the table view may be called before awakeFromNib is called if the data source is specified in Interface Builder. You should defend against this by having the data source’s numberOfRowsInTableView: method return 0 for the number of rows when the data source has not yet been configured. In awakeFromNib, when the data source is initialized you should always call reloadData on the table view.

Now, I don’t initialize in `-awakeFromNib` (I do it in `-viewDidLoad`), but this nonetheless says that you should **always call `-reloadData` on the table view that you’re a data source for.**

It can be all too easy to get this wrong; often times, the table view will automatically load its data without any extra `reload` calls required. It does seem, however, that in some rare occasions this can fail to happen.

So, to prevent this problem: **always call `-reloadData` on the table view that you’re a data source for after initialization**—in `-viewDidLoad`, `-awakeFromNib`, or some other appropriate method.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting a shitstorm of downvotes, but you helped me, and I appreciate that. Your 2 downvotes subtract 2 rep, but my upvote gives 10 rep. +8 overall :)